# Handling a click event in an Ember View

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to make a `ol` element expand when a link below it is clicked. I know how to make it expand when the `ol` itself is clicked.

```
App.MemberListingView = Ember.View.extend({
  isExpanded: false,
  classNameBindings: ['isExpanded'],
  click: function() {
    return this.toggleProperty('isExpanded');
  }
});
```

The template:

```
{{#view 'App.MemberListingView'}}
    <ol class="member-listing">
        {{#each}}
          {{user-card user=this}}
        {{/each}}
    </ol>
    <a href="#">Click here to see all</a>
{{/view}}
```

I want my anchor element to be the click trigger, not the `ol` itself. How do I do this? Do I have to write a separate view for the link?

Comment: Just out of curiosity but why not just add an action and handle it instead of using the click event on the view?  You could also pass in what is clicked and see if it matches what you wanted but it seems like a perfect example of when to use an action...

Comment: @PWKad To be honest I am learning EmberJS now. So I am still not familiar with many concepts. This is a UI tweak. I saw this technique on CodeSchool. They use it to expand reviews with long text on product pages. In my case I have a list of objects, users, and I want to show the first 5 items unless the user clicks to see more. Then I expand it. If you think you know a better way, I would appreciate you sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @PWKad The user list is inside a group view. So my context is group, and I'm expanding/retracting its list of members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still very new to Ember as well but this should work -

```
{{#view 'App.MemberListingView'}}
    <ol class="member-listing">
        {{#each}}
          {{user-card user=this}}
        {{/each}}
    </ol>
    <a href="#" {{action 'expandIt' target='view'}}>Click here to see all</a>
{{/view}}
```

And in your view (or controller) -

```
App.MemberListingController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  isExpanded: false,
  classNameBindings: ['isExpanded'],
  actions: {
    expandIt: function() {
        return this.toggleProperty('isExpanded');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you can use actions inside views? I tried your suggestion, but I see an error saying to the effect of nothing was registered to handle the action in the controller.

Comment: OK. In order for this to work, I need to pass the view as a target in the action call: `action 'expandIt' target='view'`. I submitted an edit to this answer.

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton Not sure why the reviewers rejected your edit but I more or less added it back - I believe you need to add the actions in the controller for your view, not in the view itself, which is why I parenthesized the controller.  If you can get a jsBin working I can help tweak more.

Comment: I can confirm that you have to pass the `target='view'` I read it in the docs. I will submit another edit. I have it working.

Comment: Three of my edits, which are correct have been rejected. Some editors are trigger happy, it seems. Here are the docs: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_specifying-a-target

Comment: Hahah that's awesome!  I love the edit comment.  Sorry I would have approved it but someone is beating me to it.

Comment: Heheheh... got frustrated, that's all :D